# How to create new Sqlite meta-command

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite, metaprogramming

In Sqlite shell there are many util meta-command ([list](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sqlite31.html)).

Is there a way to create a new one?
Or, why not, modify another one.

We could create a new meta-command like ".all" that is a shortcut for "select * from $1" or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change or add dot commands in the `sqlite3` command-line shell, you would have to modify [its source code](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/finfo?name=src/shell.c).

Comment: so there's no simply way to register new command.. this could be an improvement! So I need to find "where" commands are defined in the code, modify and compile it. Boring! Do you already know where commands are defined?